# find the general solution to the system of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let A=$\left [ \begin{matrix}
    5 & -6 &-6 \\
    -1 & 4 &2 \\
    3  &-6 &-4\\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$  I know that the eigenvalue be $1$ and $2$ also I find the eigenvector for $1$ is $(3,-1,3)$, since it has repeat eigenvalue, I only find the one eigenvector for $2$ is $(2,1,0)$, how can I find the other linearly independent eigenvector to get the general solution $y=.....$( I am not sure when I need $t e^{2t}$ as a linear term )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    5 & -6 &-6 \\
    -1 & 4 &2 \\
    3  &-6 &-4\\
   \end{bmatrix} $$

For the repeated eigenvalue $\lambda = 2$, we have the RREF $[A-\lambda I]v_i=0$ as

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & -2 & -2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}v_i = \begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\
 0 \\
 0  \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

From this, we can generate two linearly independent eigenvectors as

$$v_1 = (2, 0, 1)\\ v_2 = (2, 1 , 0)$$

If we cannot find linearly independent eigenvectors, we have a deficient matrix and would have to resort to [*generalized eigenvectors*](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Emoose/240S2013/slides7-31.pdf).

You should find the general solution

$$\begin{align} x(t) &=  c_1 e^t \left(4 e^t-3\right)-6 c_2 e^t \left(e^t-1\right)-6 c_3 e^t \left(e^t-1\right)\\ y(t) &= c_1 \left(-e^t\right) \left(e^t-1\right)+c_2 e^t \left(3 e^t-2\right)+2 c_3 e^t \left(e^t-1\right) \\ z(t) &= 3 c_1 e^t \left(e^t-1\right)-6 c_2 e^t \left(e^t-1\right)-c_3 e^t \left(5 e^t-6\right) \end{align}$$

Comment: how do you get the general solution in that form, I always find that different form as eigenvalue and eigenvector summation

Comment: If you multiply each exponential out, you see the eigenvalue results you found. For example, $c_1e^t(4e^t-3) = 4 c_1e^{2t} - 3c_1e^t$. This factoring is just a matter of choice as it could be written in many different ways..